# Convert String to ZonedDateTime and change TimeZone

Tags: java, datetime, zoneddatetime

I have this string `"Tue Apr 09 2019 12:59:51 GMT+0300"`

I want to convert to `ZonedDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss OOOO");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(a, dtf);
```

After convert to `ZonedDateTime`, I want to change the timezone from `GMT+0300` to other timezone.

My first problem is at `parse`. I get:

`DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue Apr 09 2019 12:59:51 GMT+0300' could not be parsed at index 25` (at GMT+0300, I think `OOOO` it's not right, but I don't know what else it is)

After that I don't know how to change the timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OOOO` expects the a colon before minute field, as the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) says:

> Four letters outputs the full form, which is localized offset text,
>   such as 'GMT, with 2-digit hour and minute field, optional second
>   field if non-zero, and colon, for example 'GMT+08:00'.

You can insert a `:` before the last `00` programmatically, then parse it.

Comment: I inserted `:` and now I can parse. Thanks! But I still don't know how to change timezone.

Comment: @KunLun call this method `withZoneSameInstant`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-

Answer (score 2):

Since your string contains an offset and no time zone, what do you want a `ZonedDateTime` for? `OffsetDateTime` is more appropriate.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx", Locale.ROOT);
    String a = "Tue Apr 09 2019 12:59:51 GMT+0300";
    System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(a, dtf));
```

> 2019-04-09T12:59:51+03:00

A time zone is a place on earth and encompasses historic and known future changes in UTC offset in that place. A time zone is conventionally given in the *region/city* format, for example Asia/Rangoon.

**Edit**

> I use ZonedDateTime because I use time zone in my app.

I’m unsure exactly what you mean. Maybe you have decided in advance which time zone you are using? For example:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Zaporozhye");
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(a, dtf);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(zone);
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

> 2019-04-09T12:59:51+03:00[Europe/Zaporozhye]

If for some reason you want to regard GMT+0300 as a time zone even though it isn’t, the parsing I showed first works with `ZonedDateTime` too:

```
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(a, dtf));
```

> 2019-04-09T12:59:51+03:00

Comment: I use ZonedDateTime because I use time zone in my app.